# TinyMCE 5 extended_valid_elements not automatically working

Tags: javascript, class, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have my custom class adding to UL tag,
But it is not working unless i click code <> and click save.
Did i missed something?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    toolbar: 'bullist code',
    content_css: [
        '../../css/custom.css',
    ],
    extended_valid_elements: 'ul[class=myCustomClass]',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally fix my problem, If anyone is wondering.
instead of using extended_valid_elements use this

```
 setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
        if (e.command === 'InsertUnorderedList'){
            tinymce.activeEditor.dom.addClass(
                tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), 'myClass'
            );
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `extended_valid_elements` you have in your first example works just fine:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/F7haab

If you are not getting the class added to the `ul` tag there may be something else conflicting with that in your configuration?

[image]